# Android 11 dialog in fullscreen doesn't work

Tags: android, dialog, fullscreen

When I set a dialog in full screen it isn't really fullscreen.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQfXN.png)

How can I fix that?

```
  Window window = getWindow();
    layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    window.setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

This code is in a custom dialog class that extends Dialog.
That's why I am able to write only getWindow().

Actually I don't need it to be fullscreen but I need atleast the pixel difference between the screen and the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following theme to dialog's second parameter android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen

```
Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
```